# how to read token from header by js

Tags: javascript, token, access-token

I'm trying to read token from header by plain java script , so I have two pages 
A page request B page by

```
var B  = function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'b.html',
        method:'get',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            //do some handle functions
        },
        error: function(error){
            console.log(error);
        },
        beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) { xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization','Bearer ' + access_token ); }
      });
}
```

so, now i want read Authorization access token in B page by javascript !

Comment: Have you figured out the solution as to how to extract the authorization token in b.html?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the XMLHttpRequest.getAllResponseHeaders() method to find the token header and retrieve the response.

More Information can be found at : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest

Comment: I saw you link but I found a example for response's header I want to read request's header